# Saved image is different when read in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, processing

I created an matrix using some calculation.I saved it in the **BMP** format.But when I am reading it back in MATLAB,the content of it changes totally.Only where value is **0** is correct.All other pixels are having values **255[image]**.Why is this.How to solve this??
It is showing image correctly when **imsec** command is used

```
 for i=1:length(pixel_matrix)
     pixel=char(pixel_matrix(i));
     r=7;

     pixel_value=0;
     for j=1:4
         s=r-1;
         if(pixel(j)=='A')
             temp_bin=0;
         elseif(pixel(j)=='B')
             temp_bin=(2^r)+(2^s);
         elseif(pixel(j)=='C')
             temp_bin=(2^s);
         elseif(pixel(j)=='D')
             temp_bin=(2^r);
         end

     pixel_value=pixel_value+temp_bin;
     r=r-2;


     end
     pixel_row(i)=pixel_value;
 end


 i=1;
 j=1;
 for m=1:length(pixel_row)

     pixel_value(i,j)=pixel_row(m);
     j=j+1;
     if(j==65)
         i=i+1;
         j=1;
     end
     end

     for i=1:64
         for j=1:64
             picture(i,j)=uint8(pixel_value(i,j));
         end
 end

 imwrite(picture,'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\pic.bmp');

 aaaa=imread('C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\pic.bmp');
```

Comment: Upload the image somewhere and link it here?

Comment: image is a white one except two or three black dots.

Comment: Post the code you used to create, edit and save the image

Comment: I think @Divakar is asking for the input image, not the result image...

Comment: @phyrox, I don't think he has input as an image, so OP putting his code is good, but the code is hard to understand with the inputs to the code not clearly mentioned or defined.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is most likely that you are filling `picture` with `uint8` values, but when not specified otherwise, images in MatLab are doubles between 0 and 1. Try using the `Map` option for `imwrite` or norm the values of `pixel_value(i,j)` to fit them between 0 and 1 like this:

```
%...
 for i=1:64
     for j=1:64
         picture(i,j)=pixel_value(i,j)/255; %<- Norm things here...
     end
 end
```